# Hyper-V checkpoint, automate

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server

I wanna ask about special scenario regarding hyper-v checkpoint.

I have requirements to take a checkpoint (aka snapshot) every 1 hour automatically. From the add-in console i can see only a menu to do snapshot.

Kindly advise and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with the Task Scheduler and a PowerShell script using the Checkpoint-VM cmdlet.

For example, to create a checkpoint of a VM named "VM1":

```
Checkpoint-VM -Name "VM1"
```

or all running VMs:

```
Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Running"} | Checkpoint-VM
```

Remember to delete/merge the checkpoints. For example, to delete checkpoints older than 3 hours:

```
Get-VM | Get-VMSnapshot | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-3)} | Remove-VMSnapshot
```

---

[Get-VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/Get-VM?view=win10-ps)
[Checkpoint-VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/Checkpoint-VM?view=win10-ps)
[Get-VMSnapshot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/Get-VMSnapshot?view=win10-ps)
[Remove-VMSnapshot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/Remove-VMSnapshot?view=win10-ps)